# javaws blocking Google Maps access

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm working in a SWT Java application that shows a map, when I launch the application from Eclipse everything is OK but when I launch the generated JNLP file, Java Web Start is blocking the call to Google Maps.

What should I do?

Comment: *"Java Web Start is blocking the call to Google Maps."*  DYM JWS or the security manager that is imposed on JWS apps.?  It seems there is far too little information here to solve this.  But some tips:  1) Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). 2) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: Once you've validated the JNLP (and solved the red 'errors') you might also post it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31406643/edit) (use code formatting so it is visible).